# How to install Extreme tux Racer

Tags: games, c++

I have extracted down Extreme tux racer in my home folder, after extracting it in same folder, i run commands-

```
~/game/autorun.sh
~/game/./configure
```

then following commands run-

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for g++... no
checking for c++... no
checking for gpp... no
checking for aCC... no
checking for CC... no
checking for cxx... no
checking for cc++... no
checking for cl.exe... no
checking for FCC... no
checking for KCC... no
checking for RCC... no
checking for xlC_r... no
checking for xlC... no
checking whether the C++ compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/username/game':
configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

What is the problem and what are the solution for this?
http://sourceforge.net/projects/extremetuxracer/
I have files saved on my hdd, so i am not wanting to download from Ubuntu app store

Comment: As you can see, there is no c++ compiler installed in your system. First installed a compiler like g++, or better install `build-essential` package using `sudo apt-get install build-essential`

Comment: when i run sudo apt-get install gcc , it is already in it's newest version, what should i run?

Comment: @aVIRA `sudo apt-get install build-essential`, as g_p has already stated.

Comment: it is too in latest version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, one simple way is :

1. Open **Ubuntu Software Center**
2. Search for, **Extreme Tux Racer**
3. Install, by clicking the **install** button provided.

**OR**

**1. Unpack the code tarball:**

`shell$ tar xvfz tuxracer-<version>.tar.gz`
`shell$ cd tuxracer-<version>`

**2. Configure for your system:**

`shell$ ./configure <configure options>`

Many people will be able to run configure without passing any options. The more commonly-used configure options are:

`--prefix=DIR: Specify where to install tuxracer. (The tuxracer binary will be placed in DIR/bin)
--with-tcl-libs=DIR: Specify Tcl library location
--with-tcl-inc=DIR: Specify Tcl header file location
--with-tcl-lib-name=NAME: Specify Tcl library base name
--with-gl-libs=DIR: Specify OpenGL library location
--with-gl-inc=DIR: Specify OpenGL header file location
--with-glut-libs=DIR: Specify GLUT library location
--with-glut-inc=DIR: Specify GLUT header file location
--enable-stencil-buffer: Use if your hardware has a stencil buffer
--with-data-dir=PATH: Location of tuxracer data directory (can be also configured in options file later)`

Run ./configure --help for a complete list of options.

**3. Compile:**

`shell$ make`

Tux Racer should compile cleanly, with few (if any) warnings. Please see the [FAQ#compilation](http://tuxracer.sourceforge.net/faq.html#linux_opengl_problems) or our Support page if Tux Racer fails to compile.

**4. Install the tuxracer binary:**

`shell$ make install`

Unless you specified the --prefix option when you ran configure, this command will install the tuxracer binary in /usr/local/bin

**5. Install the data files:**

`shell$ cd /usr/local/share`
`shell$ tar xvfz /path/to/tuxracer-data-<version>.tar.gz`
`shell$ mv tuxracer-data-<version> tuxracer`

You may install the data files anywhere you wish, but tuxracer looks in /usr/local/share/tuxracer by default.

**6. You're done!**

Comment: whole package it in my hdd. That's why I am not wanting to install from software centre

Comment: @aVIRA package will automatically be downloaded, extracted and installed for you by the software center.

Comment: Sir, all I am asking is, is there anything I am missing or anything could be done for installing it. If i started download it would take 5-6 hrs., because transfer rate is very slow at my area.

Comment: after running command make, it shows error - make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

Comment: @aVIRA Click on the **FAQ#compilation** link under the Compile section.

Answer (score 5):

**Extreme Tux Racer** is in [Official Ubuntu Repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=tux&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all).

You can install it without difficult compilations by:

```
sudo apt-get install extremetuxracer
```